# Predicate Logic Quantfier and Brackets

Tags: logic, predicate, first-order-logic

Taken from: https://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/pred-examples.html

Let U be a universe containing people and songs. Let L be a language with the following primitives.

```
c(P,S) --- Person P composed song S.
l(P,S) --- Person P likes song S.
s(P,S) --- Person P sings song S.
m(S) --- Song S is in a major key.
Constants: a --- Amy; b --- Barry; d --- David; y -- Yankee Doodle.
```

David likes some of the songs that Amy has written (i.e. at least one song).
exists(S) c(a,S) ^ l(d,S).

Is there a difference in meaning between exists(S) c(a,S) ^ l(d,S) vs exists(S) [c(a,S) ^ l(d,S)]?

Answer (score 1):

`exists(S) c(a,S) ^ l(d,S)` is ambiguous. It could mean either `exists(S) [c(a,S) ^ l(d,S)]` or `exists(S) [c(a,S)] ^ l(d,S)`. The two formulas are different. The former is a closed formula that is also often called sentence, the latter is a formula with free variables.

You can get a better idea of the difference between the two formulas. By applying a renaming rule to the closed subformula of the latter you get

```
exists(R) [c(a,R)] ^ l(d,S)
```

This formula means *`a` has composed some song and `d` likes song `S`*.

In print certain convention is usually set on resloving such ambiguity to avoid throwing in to many brackets into formulas. However no universal convention exists.

In my experience logical connectives usually bind stronger than quantifiers. If this convention is taken the ambiguity is resolved towards the first option, that is
`exists(S) c(a,S) ^ l(d,S)` is expected to mean `exists(S) [c(a,S) ^ l(d,S)]`. However you have to check that before relying on it.